# Php organized like ruby on rails

Tags: php

I really like php, but I like how rails organizes it's files.  I'm wondering if there is a framework where I can use the MVC-type-of-thing in php.

Comment: yes, many. and the question is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141945/lightest-possible-php-mvc among many other such questions here. Try searching for `PHP MVC`.

Comment: PHP MVC frameworks are like pimples on a teenager, so many of them, and they keep coming up.. did you even try google first?

Comment: symfony's file structure was inspired by RoR. It works around most of php's quirks in creative ways.

Comment: You should also look into the Front Controller design pattern, and possibly Inversion of Control pattern. In addition to MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay away from the giants like zend or symfony these are really good.

- CodeIgniter: http://codeigniter.com/
- CakePhp: http://cakephp.org/
- fuelPhp: http://fuelphp.com/
- Kohana: http://kohanaframework.org/